# Count columns that ends with the same value starting with a value you choose

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-query

I have a table which is like:

| Identfier |
| --- |
| Abc XY: a(123) |
| Abcd XY: a(123) |
| Abcde XY: b(123) |
| dfe XY: b(123) |
| dfeg XY: b(123) |
| dfegh XY: c(123) |
| ijk XY: c(123) |

I want to count columns
that they end with the same value starting from a certain value I choose
It doesn't matter how the columns start
For example if I chose "XY" in our example ,I have an output like this:

| Identifier last part | number of repetition |
| --- | --- |
| XY: a(123) | 2 |
| XY: b(123) | 3 |

Thank you.

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: It would be a costly operation to do this using `SQL`

Comment: `group by substring(id, charindex('XY', id),999)`

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
Create Table tblText1(data  nvarchar(Max))

Insert into tblText1(data) values('Abc XY: a(123)')
Insert into tblText1(data) values('Abcd XY: a(123)')
Insert into tblText1(data) values('Abcde XY: b(123)')
Insert into tblText1(data) values('dfe XY: b(123)')
Insert into tblText1(data) values('dfeg XY: b(123)')
Insert into tblText1(data) values('dfegh XY: c(123)')
Insert into tblText1(data) values('ijk XY: c(123)')
```

[image]

```
Select distinct Right(data,Len(data)-charindex('XY:',data)+1) as [Identifier last part],Count(data) over (partition By Right(data,Len(data)-charindex('XY:',data)+1) ) as [number of repetition] from tblText1
```

[image]

In this example first, you need to calculate the end part of the column and then add a partition to it.

Comment: Why a window function, why not just a normal aggregate?